# If a family $\{f_n\}$, is uniformly integrable, then also $\{|f_n|\}$ is.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, uniform-integrability

I want to show that if a set of functions $\{f_n\}_n$ is uniformly integrable, then also $\{|f_n|\}_n$ is also uniformly integrable. How can I show this?
My guess is to use separate $f_n$ into real and imaginary part and then use negative and positive part for each R/I part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the [following characterization of the uniform integrability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_integrability#Related_corollaries) of $f_n$:
$$
\lim_{c\to\infty}\sup_n\int_{\{x:|f_n(x)| > c\}} |f_n(u)|du = 0
$$ 
it follows immediately that $(f_n)$ is uniformly integrable iff $(|f_n)|)$ is.